# How do I call three requests in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node. I have a console app that must make requests to web services in order. Specifically, I need to make three requests in order. In an attempt to make these requests, I'm using the built-in [HTTPS module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html). I have one request successfully executing. But, I need to make three in succession. I'm not sure how to do this. Right now, I have:

```
console.log('Running Request #1...');
var options = {
  host: 'example.com',
  path: '/api/service',
  port: 443,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'api-key': '[Hidden]'
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  res.on('data', (d) => {});
});
req.end();

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

I'm not sure how to call my three requests in order. Yet, at the same time, gracefully handling an error. If I had promises, I would know how to chain them together and just use the `catch` handler. But, I'm not sure how to chain together requests since the HTTPS module uses the Arrow function syntax.

Any help is appreciated it.

Comment: You can consider either using callback or promise to chain the 3 requests in series. for async, i recommend you to have a look at [async#series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.series), for promise you can look at Guigui's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var https = require('https');
  var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

  var request = function(url) {
    console.log(url);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      https.get(url, (res) => {
        res.on('end', () => {
          resolve('what');
        });

        res.on('data', data =>{

        });
      }).on('error', e => {
        reject(e);
      });
    });
  };

  var promise = request(urls.shift());
  while(urls.length > 0) {
    let url = urls.shift();
    promise = promise.then(function() {
      return request(url);
    });
  }
  promise.catch(e => console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

consider use promise with reduce,something like this

```
var urls=['u1','u2','u3'];

var er=0

function getPromise(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(url+ " is resolved in 2 sec")
            er++
            if(er==1)
            {
                reject(url)
            }else{
                resolve(url)
            }


        },2000)
    })
}



urls.reduce(function (pre,cur) {
    return pre.then(function () {
        return getPromise(cur)
    })
},new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    resolve(null)
}))

.then(function (result) {
    console.log("final result is "+result)
},function (e) {
    console.log("something wrong happens : "+e)
})
```

Play with the code,I think it is want you want