# How do I call 3 requests async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have to do a functionality to test if 3 APIs are running.
Thus, the user will click on the Test APIs button and it will return the status of each API (status: 200, 500, 404 etc). If an API return an error, I should show the error stack.
Screen example:

```
API       Status      Detail
url1.com   200          -
url2.com   200          -
url3.com   500     internal server error
```

My question is, how can I call the 3 requests in parallel and return the async result, I mean how can I update the screen of API request status  without having to wait for the result of all requests

I was basing on that [How do I call three requests in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480838/how-do-i-call-three-requests-in-order), but it returns the result synchronously.

*******EDIT*****

Thats my current code

```
app.get('/testDependencies', function (req, res, next) {    

    let objTestsResul = {}        
    var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
    let index = 0
    while(urls.length > 0) {
      let url = urls.shift();
      objTestsResult[index++] = testURL(url)

   }

    res.send(objTestsResult)
});
```

This function is the same for each URL:

```
function testURL(URL){

   fetch(URL, {
        method: 'GET'      
    })
        .then(res => {
            res.json()            
        })
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json)
            return json      
         })
        .catch(error => {            
            return error
          })
}
```

Comment: Did you check `Promise.all`?

Comment: You're going to have to show the code we're supposed to fix.

Comment: In this case, I'm gonna update the table only when all the promises resolves, right? I'd like to update it without wait for all

Comment: Please post what you have so far :)

Comment: @tadman to be honest, I didn't figured it out how to implement it. I'm more focus on the idea about how to do it. My code is doing it synchronously

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna update the question with the code so far

Comment: In that case just make all the requests separately, and make each one update its own element on the screen (or append content to a single existing element). Literally just 3 separate, independent requests will do what you need. Nothing clever required. If this is client-side Ajax, that is (which runs async by default). Or are you talking about server side code?

Comment: If you show us what you have, we can usually make minor adaptations to it to do what you want. Starting from scratch involves a whole lot of guesswork, and may result in code that has nothing to do with what you're actually doing.

Comment: Have you considered [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) with [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)? I find that's ideal for this situation.

Comment: @ADyson it's about server side code. In frontend the user will click just once in a button "Test all"

Comment: I updated the question with my current code. I know this is not close to what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promises` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) seem to be what you're looking for. They're essentially a more readable version of callbacks, which allow you to execute code when something else occurs rather than having to wait for that trigger to occur before resuming execution.

```js
let endpoint1 = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('200'), 1000));
  let endpoint2 = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('201'), 2000));
  let endpoint3 = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('500'), 1500));

  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'test running...';
    Promise.all([
      endpoint1().then(a => document.getElementById('result1').textContent = a),
      endpoint2().then(a => document.getElementById('result2').textContent = a),
      endpoint3().then(a => document.getElementById('result3').textContent = a),
    ]).then(() => document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'test complete');
  });
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
<div>status: <span id="status">not running</span></div>
<div>endpoint 1: <span id="result1"></span></div>
<div>endpoint 2: <span id="result2"></span></div>
<div>endpoint 3: <span id="result3"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty straightforward if you can use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html):

```
const { Promise } = require('bluebird');

app.get('/testDependencies', function (req, res, next) {    
  Promise.map(['url1', 'url2', 'url3'], url => testURL(url)).then(results => {
     res.send(results);
  });
});
```

You'll just need to ensure your promise function actually returns a promise:

```
function testURL(URL) {
  let start_time = new Date().getTime();   

  return fetch(URL, {
    method: 'GET'      
  }).then(res => {
    res.json()            
  }).then(json => {
    console.log(json)
    return json      
  }).catch(error => {            
    return error
  })
}
```

Promises can't be dependency chained unless you explicitly return them from the function that's involved in chaining.

If you're able to use `async` and `await`, I'd also recommend doing that as well as that can vastly simplify otherwise complex code.

Answer (score 1):

Express can't send multiple responses. You will have to finish all calls or use `WebSockets` to stream data.

```js
function testURL(URL) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (URL === 'url2') {
      reject(new Error('Internal Server Error'));
      return;
    }
    resolve({ status: 200 });
  });
}

const main = async () => {
  const urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

  // return resolved and rejected Promises because if one fails in Promise.all
  // the function will throw and we won't have any access to any resolved Promises.
  const results = await Promise.all(urls
    .map(url => testURL(url).then(response => response).catch(error => error)));

  // every error have a stack property, Set the status to whatever you want
  // based on the error and store the stack and the message
  const objTestsResul = results.reduce((result, cur, i) => {
    result[urls[i]] = cur.stack
      ? { status: 500, message: cur.message, stack: cur.stack }
      : cur;
    return result;
  }, {});

  console.log(objTestsResul);
};

main();
```